# selecting from a multi-dimesional array with a list of indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, indexing, numpy-slicing

Let's say I have an array with size `batch` x `max_len` x `output_size`, where `batch`, `max_len`, and `output_size` all correspond to positive natural numbers. I have a list of indices which correspond to individual items in dimension 1 (i.e. `max_len`). How can I select from the array given these indices?

As a concrete example, let's say I have the following:

```
>>> l = np.random.randn(4,5,6)
>>> l.shape
(4, 5, 6)
>>> idx = [0,0,2,3]
```

When I select `l` given `idx` I get:

```
>>> l[:,idx,:].shape
(4, 4, 6)
>>>
```

I also tried `np.take` but reached the same result:

```
>>> np.take(l,idx,axis=1).shape
(4, 4, 6)
>>>
```

However, the output I am looking after is `(4,1,6)` as I am trying to have only one item looking at each element in the `batch` (i.e. first dimension). How can I produce the output with the proper shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`np.take_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) after extending `idx` to have same ndims as `l` -

```
np.take_along_axis(l,np.asarray(idx)[:,None,None],axis=1)
```

With explicit integer-array indexing -

```
l[np.arange(len(idx)),idx][:,None] # skip [:,None] for (4,6) shaped o/p
```